# Excel Copy Formulas Horizontally

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

On Row 1, Column A I have =Sheet!1K2, on Column B I have =Sheet!1K3, Column C =Sheet!1K3 and so on.

On Row 2, Column A I Have =Sheet!1L2, on Column B I have =Sheet!1L3, Column C =Sheet!1L3 and so on.

I'm trying to copy them with the same formula, but when I copy from Row 1 to 2, the row reference changes. Like if I copy from Row 2, Column A to Row 3, Column A, what pastes is =Sheet!1L3 instead of =Sheet!1M2 as I want it to do.

In other words, what I want is that **copying the formula horizontally should update the vertical (row) reference and not the horizontal (column) reference.**

How to I copy them without having to manually change the column and row reference?

Comment: It sounds like your example is somewhat irrelevant to the actual question and that the answer addresses that.  However, the example is confusing, perhaps because you copied and pasted.  You show columns B and C containing the same reference.  Perhaps that's correct, but people can get hung up on making sense of the formulas instead of the actual issue.  Even if what you show is correct for your spreadsheet, you might want to change the example to make the column C entries refer to K4 and L4 instead of K3 and L3.  Then the example won't be a stumbling block for the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand exactly the effect you are after, but if you want to be able to copy (or drag to extend) a formula while keeping some reference the same, you can prefix either the column or row (or both) identifier with a `$` sign.

For example, if you have in cell A1 `=B3` and copy this to cell A2, it becomes `=B4` because the reference is updated to reflect the new location. If instead you similarly start out with `=B$3` and do the same copy operation, the formula remains `=B$3` because the `$` sign (attached to the `3` following it) forces the reference to be fixed.

The same works with column references as well. For example, `=$B3` in A1 copied to B1 would become `=$B3` instead of `=C3`. `=$B3` in A1 copied to A2 becomes `=$B4` because only the row reference is updated.

To lock both row and column references, prefix both with `$` signs. For example, `=$B$3`.

This works (or should work, at least) anywhere a cell reference is valid.

Comment: Then thing is I want to copy horizontally AND vertically, so =B2 on cell A2, then =B3 on cell B2, then =B4 on cell C2. Then =C2 on cell A3, =C3 on cell B3 and =C4 on cell C3  But it's not letting me even when I use $ sign on the reference.

Comment: @Kali So you're looking to copy a cell horizontally, **but** have the row reference incremented rather than the column reference which would normally be the case?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly!

Comment: @Kali I see. In that case this answer obviously doesn't help you. I have edited your question; please let me know if the edit describes what you want to do. If it does, I will delete this answer because it's not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using the `OFFSET` function, along with counting the `COLUMNS` as you fill across them in your new sheet. Paste the following into A1 on your new sheet:

`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$K$3,COLUMNS($A$1:A1)-1,0)`

The `OFFSET` function starts at the cell you tell it to, and looks a given number of cells right or down from it to retrieve a different result. `COLUMNS($A$1:A1)-1` counts how many columns you've filled across in your new sheet (subtracting one so the first one uses an offset of ZERO). When you fill this formula right and it will start from `Sheet1!$K$3` and retrieve the rows below it.